# Besides the httpd.conf, where can the certificate and private key be defined?

Tags: apache-2.2, ssl, redhat

I'm updating an SSL Certificate on Apache 2 (redhat 5.6) server with virtual hosts. Normally I would expect to find the directives pointing to the crt and key in the httpd.conf, perhaps within the virtual host setting, however in this environment it is nowhere to be found.

Where else can one define these variables?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look in `/etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf` for the entries `SSLCertificateFile` and `SSLCertificateKeyFile`.

Comment: Brilliant. Now I have to work out why my grep command didn't find this. cheers